# Xpath syntax showing an error

Tags: xpath, phpunit, dynamic-data

I'm trying to test dynamic id's with PHPUnit so i choose to use xpath to check if the element contains the id specified, but when ever i run my test it gives me the error that Invalid xpath.

My xpath code is as follows

> $this->click("xpath=//div[@contains(@id,'ROOT')]")

What can i be doing wrong guys?

Thanks
Donald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `@` that's just before `contains`.